# Why apple says Operation is abstract class?

Tags: nsoperation, foundation

If swift does not have abstract class, then why apple says `Operation` is abstract class?

From the foundation documentation, operation is:

> An abstract class that represents the code and data associated with a single task.

Comment: It says the same for Objective-C. The documentation is language independent. It's conceptually abstract even if the language(s) involved don't actually support true abstract classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also from the same documentation:

> Because the NSOperation class is an abstract class, you do
>   not use it directly but instead subclass or use one of the
>   system-defined subclasses (NSInvocationOperation or NSBlockOperation)
>   to perform the actual task. Despite being abstract, the base
>   implementation of NSOperation does include significant logic to
>   coordinate the safe execution of your task. The presence of this
>   built-in logic allows you to focus on the actual implementation of
>   your task, rather than on the glue code needed to ensure it works
>   correctly with other system objects.

NSOperation has its concrete counterparts, for example, `NSBlockOperation`

> The NSBlockOperation class is a concrete subclass of NSOperation that
>   manages the concurrent execution of one or more blocks. You can use
>   this object to execute several blocks at once without having to create
>   separate operation objects for each. When executing more than one
>   block, the operation itself is considered finished only when all
>   blocks have finished executing.
>
> Blocks added to a block operation are dispatched with default priority
>   to an appropriate work queue. The blocks themselves should not make
>   any assumptions about the configuration of their execution
>   environment.

Although Objective-C does not provide abstract classes formally as other programming languages do (E.G: Java) it's possible to implement them, and Apple does it in many elements of their SDKs.